# How to enable and disable firebase pushnotification programatically android

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on push notification functionality. I am enabling and disabling push notification functionality based on choices. By default i kept push notification enabled = false in manifest for enabling i am using component settings but that is not working after restart app only i am receiving notifications.

```
context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
                        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

                context.startService(new Intent(context, FcmFirebaseService.class)
```

Comment: Instead of your way you can set condition at notification generation code you can check user has enable/disable the notification.

Comment: but android provided this way also right

Comment: Is componentName something like `new ComponentName(context, FcmFirebaseService.class);`?

Comment: yes i have given like this

Comment: What do you get in Log when this code is run?

Comment: I am not getting anything based on this